# C# DataGridView alinhar header no centro

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou sofrendo para conseguir alinhar o cabeçalho do DataGridView. Quero que o texto fique centralizado no centro.

Eis o código:

```
        dg.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false; // Desabilita formatação padrão
        dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
        dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

O resultado fica como na figura seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele fica alinhado no centro, mas puxado para a esquerda. Há como por o texto 100% centralizado? Já procurei no fórum mas encontrei ninguém com esse problema.

O código é parte de uma função que recebe um DataGridView, formata e retorna com a formatação. Segue o código completo:

```
    public DataGridView Grade(DataGridView dg){
        dg.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
        dg.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dg.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dg.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dg.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Calibri", 9);
        dg.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false; // Desabilita formatação padrão
        dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
        dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dg.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
        dg.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        dg.MultiSelect = false;
        return dg;
    }
```

Esta função fica na classe Design e é chamada nas outras pelo código:

```
public void DataGridViewDesign(){
    Design modelo = new Design();
    dgDados = modelo.Grade(dgDados);
}
```

Todos os Grids da aplicação ficam com a mesma aparência.

Comment: É Windows forms?

Comment: Sim, é Windows Forms. Usei o Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @LindomarLemos Coloque o trecho da rotina responsável por chamar o método `Grade()` também.

Comment: Coloquei o código que chama a função. Ele é o mesmo em toda o aplicativo.

Comment: Estou testando aqui.

Comment: @LindomarLemos Adiciona a linha no método `Grade()` veja se funciona: `dg.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;`

Comment: Esse código é pra célula, nela funcionou deixando o texto das células alinhado à esquerda e a altura centralizada. A distância em cima e embaixo é a mesma.

Comment: @LindomarLemos Fiz uma modificação aqui e resolveu, deixou o Header no centro, vou editar a minha resposta.

Comment: Desculpe, coloquei o código na função errada. Ele centralizou as células de maneira perfeita o lado esquerdo e direito tem a mesma distância. Só queria que o mesmo acontecesse com o header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia especificar as colunas, veja um pequeno exemplo:

```
dg.Columns["nomeDoMeuCampo"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

## Edição:

Consegui deixar o conteudo do Header no centro desabilitando a propriedade de ordenação:

```
public DataGridView Grade(DataGridView dg)
{
    dg.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
    dg.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    dg.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dg.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    dg.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Calibri", 9);
    dg.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false; // Desabilita formatação padrão
    dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
    dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    dg.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter;

    //Vc pode usar um for se quiser
    dg.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    dg.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    dg.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    dg.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    dg.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    dg.Columns[2].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    dg.Columns[3].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    dg.Columns[3].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    dg.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    dg.Columns[4].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

    dg.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
    dg.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    dg.MultiSelect = false;                        
    return dg;
}
```

Fonte:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72b7fbac-660a-4693-9b7f-33ae6657853b/datagridview-headertext-alignment-padding-on-the-right-or-center?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Também já tentei aplicar em cada coluna mas o resultado foi o mesmo. Já nas células funciona perfeito. Acho muito estranho ou falta eu declarar alguma coisa no código.

Comment: @LindomarLemos Tenta deixa a opção `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` habilitada (true).

Comment: Se deixar habilitada a formatação não funciona. Fica default com a cor da fonte preta, fundo cinza e alinhado à esquerda. Fiz outros testes com alinhamento à direita e também fica um espaço até a borda jogando o texto mais à esquerda.

Comment: @LindomarLemos Posta toda rotina responsável pela formatação na pergunta.

Comment: Coloquei o código completo da função na descrição, mas fora da função acontece a mesma coisa.

Comment: @LindomarLemos veja se funcionou agora.

Comment: Muito legal, funcionou sim. Só não dá pra colocar na função. Não tenho um tamanho exato de colunas em cada DataGrid em que a função é chamada, Vou ver se faço outra função passando a quantidade de colunas e retornar essa formatação. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fiz a função para alinhar o Header. Deve ser chamado: 
`dgDados = modelo.AlinharHeader(dgDados, dgDados.ColumnCount);`

Função:
`public DataGridView AlinharHeader(DataGridView dg, int colunas){
     try{
         for (int i = 0; i < colunas; i++){
             dg.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
             dg.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
          }
     }
     catch { }            
     return dg;
 }
`